# How do you signify a primary key in EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key

I am new to EF Code First.  How do you go about representing that a variable in an object should be the primary key when it is peristed to a database table?

Answer (score 4):

By default and by convention, if you have a column called `ID` or `(EntityName)ID` (e.g. `CustomerID` for an entity of type `Customer`), then that will be your primary key.

Otherwise, you need to use the `[Key]` attribute on another column.